# SELECT any row that starts with (multiple values from select statement)

Tags: c#, mysql

I an using c# and mysql server and i have two tables like this :

table_1

```
+--------+----------------------+-----------+----------------+
| aut_id | aut_name             | country   | home_city      |
+--------+----------------------+-----------+----------------+
| AUT001 | William Norton       | UK        | Cambridge      |
| AUT002 | William Maugham      | Canada    | Toronto        |
| AUT003 | William Anthony      | UK        | Leeds          |
| AUT004 | S.B.Swaminathan      | India     | Bangalore      |
| AUT005 | Thomas Morgan        | Germany   | Arnsberg       |
| AUT006 | Thomas Merton        | USA       | New York       |
| AUT007 | Piers Gibson         | UK        | London         |
| AUT008 | Nikolai Dewey        | USA       | Atlanta        |
| AUT009 | Marquis de Ellis     | Brazil    | Rio De Janerio |
| AUT010 | Joseph Milton        | USA       | Houston        |
| AUT011 | John Betjeman Hunter | Australia | Sydney         |
| AUT012 | Evan Hayek           | Canada    | Vancouver      |
| AUT013 | E. Howard            | Australia | Adelaide       |
| AUT014 | C. J. Wilde          | UK        | London         |
| AUT015 | Butler Andre         | USA       | Florida        |
+--------+----------------------+-----------+----------------+
```

table_2

```
+--------+-----+
| ID | PreFix  |
+--------+-----+
| 1  | Wi      |
| 2  | Th      |
| 3  | E       |
+--------+-----+
```

I want to select any author that his name starts with any prefix from the table_2, the results should be like :

```
+--------+----------------------+-----------+----------------+
| aut_id | aut_name             | country   | home_city      |
+--------+----------------------+-----------+----------------+
| AUT001 | William Norton       | UK        | Cambridge      |
| AUT002 | William Maugham      | Canada    | Toronto        |
| AUT003 | William Anthony      | UK        | Leeds          |
| AUT005 | Thomas Morgan        | Germany   | Arnsberg       |
| AUT006 | Thomas Merton        | USA       | New York       |
| AUT012 | Evan Hayek           | Canada    | Vancouver      |
| AUT013 | E. Howard            | Australia | Adelaide       |
+--------+----------------------+-----------+----------------+
```

i tried this solution :

SELECT * FROM tabel_1 where aut_name like concat((SELECT PreFix FROM table_2) , '%');

but i get this error message :

Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using JOIN instead of subquerying:

```sql
SELECT t1.aut_id, t1.aut_name, t1.country, t1.home_city
FROM table_1 AS t1
JOIN table_2 AS t2 ON t1.aut_name LIKE CONCAT(t2.PreFix, '%');
```

The SQL `CONCAT` function is designed to concatenate multiple strings into a single string, taking individual string values as arguments and combining them together. CONCAT expects individual **scalar values** as arguments, not a **result-set** of multiple rows which is what your subquery could potentially return.

To solve a problem like the one you laid out here, you need to leverage the power of `JOIN`, a statement allowing you to combine rows from different tables based on a related column between them, which you will usually call a foreign key. This way, you ensure that each row from `table_1` is compared with all the rows from `table_2` that have matching `PreFix` values, a condition you can specify after the `ON` clause.

As a side note, it'd be very much appreciated if you provided the SQL's DDL and DML statements to build the minimal reproducible example needed to test your case and play around. I took the liberty of creating these statements so I'll be posting them here to help any people to come by later to understand, play around with, test and improve our work:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
  aut_id VARCHAR(10),
  aut_name VARCHAR(50),
  country VARCHAR(50),
  home_city VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE table_2 (
  ID INT,
  PreFix VARCHAR(2)
);

INSERT INTO table_1 (aut_id, aut_name, country, home_city)
VALUES
  ('AUT001', 'William Norton', 'UK', 'Cambridge'),
  ('AUT002', 'William Maugham', 'Canada', 'Toronto'),
  ('AUT003', 'William Anthony', 'UK', 'Leeds'),
  ('AUT004', 'S.B.Swaminathan', 'India', 'Bangalore'),
  ('AUT005', 'Thomas Morgan', 'Germany', 'Arnsberg'),
  ('AUT006', 'Thomas Merton', 'USA', 'New York'),
  ('AUT007', 'Piers Gibson', 'UK', 'London'),
  ('AUT008', 'Nikolai Dewey', 'USA', 'Atlanta'),
  ('AUT009', 'Marquis de Ellis', 'Brazil', 'Rio De Janerio'),
  ('AUT010', 'Joseph Milton', 'USA', 'Houston'),
  ('AUT011', 'John Betjeman Hunter', 'Australia', 'Sydney'),
  ('AUT012', 'Evan Hayek', 'Canada', 'Vancouver'),
  ('AUT013', 'E. Howard', 'Australia', 'Adelaide'),
  ('AUT014', 'C. J. Wilde', 'UK', 'London'),
  ('AUT015', 'Butler Andre', 'USA', 'Florida');

INSERT INTO table_2 (ID, PreFix)
VALUES
  (1, 'Wi'),
  (2, 'Th'),
  (3, 'E');
```